# convert to a derived type using transfer fortran intrinsic : does the standard advise for byte order?

Tags: fortran

I convert -using the intrinsic transfer - a integer(c_int32_t) to a derived type composed of four bytes, does the standard says anything about the order of the bytes after conversion

```
program transfert_ex
  use iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  integer(c_int32_t) :: res

  type :: pixel 
    integer(c_int8_t) :: r
    integer(c_int8_t) :: g 
    integer(c_int8_t) :: b 
    integer(c_int8_t) :: alpha
  end type

  type(pixel) :: p1, p2
  
  integer(c_int32_t) :: rx = 33   !! 21
  integer(c_int32_t) :: gx = 28   !! 1C
  integer(c_int32_t) :: bx = 128  !! 80
  integer(c_int32_t) :: ax = 255  !! FF

  res = ieor(ishft(rx, 24), ieor(ishft(gx, 16), ieor(ishft(bx, 8), ax)))
  p2 = transfer(res, p1)
  !print "(4(z0,1x))", [p2%r, p2%g, p2%b, p2%alpha]
  print *, ichar(transfer([p2%r, p2%g, p2%b, p2%alpha], 'a', 4))

end program transfert_ex
```

returns

```
211C80FF
     255         128          28          33
```

It seems that the bytes are flip from left to right after the conversion. I test with three differents compilers (on the same architecture which is little endian) and it gives the same result. So maybe the order of the bytes in the derived type in taken into account by the standard ?

Comment: The Fortran standard says almost nothing about _bytes_.

Comment: You should define the derived type using either the `sequence` keyword or the `bind(c)` attribute. Without that, and although it is unlikely in practice, the compiler may chose to store the 4 components with internal padding (for alignment purpose) and/or out of order.

Comment: (that said it won't change the result you obtain here, it's just a general remark)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit manipulation procedures for integers like `ieor()` or `ishft()` use a Bit model defined in section 16.3 in the Fortran 2018 standard. It defines a sequence of bits from the most significant bit being the leftmost and the the least significant bit the rightmost. It does not care about how exactly the integer is stored in memory in some bytes.

If you do `transfer()` you will see how such an integers are stored in memory in individual bytes. On a little-endian architecture that order will seem reversed. This is not controlled by the standard at all. It is defined by the implementation of memory storage for integers on the particular CPU in the particular setting (some CPUs can be set for either big-endian or little-endian).

Comment: By the most part, modern CPUs are little-endian I think ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#:~:text=little%2Dendianness%20is%20the%20dominant%20ordering%20for%20processor%20architectures%20(x86%2C%20most%20ARM%20implementations%2C%20base%20RISC%2DV%20implementations)%20and%20their%20associated%20memory.)).

Comment: @JohnAlexiou RISCs are mostly originally big-endian, but the pressure of the x86 era made them to enable switching between little-endian and big-endian (ARM, MIPS) so are mostly run as little-endian. RISC-V (similar to MIPS but fresh from the start) is little-endian from the start.

Comment: But the list of architectures supported by GCC is much longer. Not all of them have also the Fortran front-end, though.